# Does Double Move allow you to cast spells or activate abilities that require swift or standard actions without changing weapon set up?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, actions, move-action

Can a character that, for example, holds a weapon in each hand, use its move action to sheathe one of them, cast a spell (a divine spell with the Quicken Spell metamagic feat which is a swift action) or activate an ability (Lay on Hands on himself which is another swift action) that's shorter than a standard move with his now free hand, then turn his standard action into another move action and unsheathe the same weapon as before?

If that character also has a Bonus Attack higher than +1, would that mean that he would be able to move as well, during both of his move actions, at his normal speed each?

If that character also has Quick Draw, does that mean that he would be able to sheathe one of his weapons using his move action, cast a spell or activate an ability that requires a standard action instead, and unsheathe his weapon as a free action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a typical human that's wielding a weapon in each hand can, on his turn, take a move action that provokes attacks of opportunity to sheathe a weapon, take a swift action to cast a spell modified by the feat Quicken Spell or take some other swift action that requires the human to use his hand, then take a second move action to draw the weapon he had previously sheathed.

A base attack bonus of at least +1 *does* allow a typical human to take a move action to move up to his speed and simultaneously *draw* a weapon, but a base attack bonus of +1 or more does *not* allow a typical human to take a move action to move up to his speed and simultaneously *sheathe* a weapon. (See [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Draw-or-Sheathe-a-Weapon).) Sheathing a weapon is typically its own separate move action that provokes attacks of opportunity.

Even the feat [Quick Draw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat/) doesn't change how long it takes to *sheathe* a weapon. The feat Quick Draw only allows *drawing* a weapon faster: as a free action instead of as a unique move action or simultaneously during a move action when the human moves up to his speed. So, for example, were that human with the feat Quick Draw adjacent to a foe yet unarmed, he could use the feat Quick Draw and take a free action to draw a weapon and still make a full attack against his foe.

---

***Note:*** Human is used for baseline because it's easy; replace with your favorite relatively similar two-handed race. For the curious, the word sheathe *is a verb ("I sheathe my sword"), and the word* sheath *is a noun ("I draw the sword from its sheath").*

Comment: If I had another upvote, I would give it for that note.